# Temporarily block communication with host if its connecting to port X

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I have a Linux VPS, and it's constantly being scanned, bruteforced by some rogue IPs. This VPS is my private server, that serves only to me, and I'm the only user of it. Also I am the only user who should be allowed to connect to it.

I would like to ask you, ServerFault, to comment on my method of 'solving' the problem and point me any problems with it, as I'm not experienced with `iptables` at all.

On my server I'm using `dovecot` on port `993` and `sshd` on port `22`. I've moved both services to nonstandard ports to `X` and `Y`, to prevent dumb bruteforce attacks on known ports. For the port-scanning issue, I've figured that I'd like to create a "trap" on standard ports `23` (telnetd), `22` (sshd), `110` (pop3), `80` (httpd), etc. If the firewall will detect that anyone wants to connect to these ports, it should block the initiating packet, along with **any** further communication with the source host for the next 24 hours, even to the ports `X` and `Y`. To do that, I'm trying to use the `recent` module of `iptables`:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 86400 --hitcount 1 -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set -j DROP
```

From my tests it would seem that it even works, but is there a *more proper* way to perform what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is an unreasonable configuration, per se. Since you're doing everything in kernel space (versus something like `fail2ban`, which runs in userland and acts upon the kernel's syslog messages) it should be reasonably efficient.

Be aware that you have a major denial-of-service attack potential here, though. An attacker can send SYNs with spoofed source addresses to any of these "trap" ports and get those IPs blocked. Sending enough packets to block a large part of the Internet wouldn't be tremendously difficult. You probably want to think about explicitly whitelisting whatever addresses you commonly use to access the server.

If it's not practical to whitelist the IPs you commonly use to access the server I don't think I'd go this route.

Comment: I knew I haven't thought about everything. This spoofing scenario is valid, though it would require a dedicated attack on my server. But still, it's a very valid reason and I think I need to think about it some more.